# Can MySQL database hold 103,998,960,000 records?

Tags: mysql, database

Will a MySQL database hold over 103,998,960,000 records or will have to spread this out between several databases?

Comment: Explain more. Because the answer may go wrong, without knowing you db structure and what is your actual requirement.

Comment: read mysql docs : http://dev.mysql.com/

Comment: I think it's as much a general architecture question as it is a MySQL-specific one. If you've got 100 billion records of anything, it seems fairly reasonable to assume that you'll need to distribute the data/processing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a little bit on the size of a record.  There is no limit ot the number of rows, but there is a 64 terrabyte limit on the size of data.

If you are within that limit and you make sure your primary key does not overflow (which it wont in your case assuming a uint primary key) then you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If table size not matter you can use a very big count of rows. From mysql documentation.

```
It is possible to build MySQL with large table support using 
the --with-big-tables option.

This option causes the variables that store table row counts to be declared as 
unsigned long long rather than unsigned long. This enables tables to hold up 
to approximately 1.844E+19 ((232)2) rows rather than 232 (~4.295E+09) rows. 
Previously it was necessary to pass -DBIG_TABLES to the compiler manually 
in order to enable this feature.
```

For more information [MySQL Source configuration.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/source-configuration-options.html)

Edit: From comments i get i should give information about engine wise.

```
There is a limit of (232)2 (1.844E+19) rows in a MyISAM table.
```

For more information about [MyISAM engine limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisam-storage-engine.html).

```
The InnoDB internal maximum key length is 3500 bytes, but MySQL itself 
restricts this to 3072 bytes. This limit applies to the length of 
the combined index key in a multi-column index.
```

For more information about [InnoDB engine limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html).

Theoretically yes but in real life there are limitations like Table size and insert time. From MySQL documentation again.

```
When an AUTO_INCREMENT column runs out of values, InnoDB wraps a BIGINT 
to -9223372036854775808 and BIGINT UNSIGNED to 1. However, BIGINT values 
have 64 bits, so if you were to insert one million rows per second, it would 
still take nearly three hundred thousand years before BIGINT reached its upper bound.
With all other integer type columns, a duplicate-key error results. This is general 
MySQL behavior, similar to how MyISAM works.
```

Comment: Big tables applies only to the MyISAM storage engine, which is virtually obsolete.